# Using 'fields' in pyes queries, failing on 0.19.1

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyes

Trying to use a fields=[...] paramater in pyes .search is failing

Here is a simple test script to illustrate the problem:
http://pastebin.com/LiRMC3ib

Using the current release of pyes 0.19.1 this script outputs {} as a result of the

```
print resultset[0]
```

However using a previous 'old' unstable 0.19.1 version of pyes which I have - 0.19.1 (unstable) the result of

```
print resultset[0]
```

is the expected:

```
{u'name': u'Joe Tester'}
```

Using fields in an ES.get call *does* work.

Anyone else seen this or have some pointers as to what's up?

Comment: I have same problem. Have you succeed to solve it?

Comment: Note, I have since switched to using the client at http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/current/ it doesn't abstract away the raw JSON API, which actually makes it a lot _easier_ to use.

Answer (score 2):

rewrite

```
resultset = ES.search(query=q, indices='oolong', fields=["name"])
```

to

```
resultset = ES.search(Search(q, fields=['name']), indices='oolong'))
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing I notice in your pastebin code that may explain the unexpected behaviour - the refresh (line 37) should be before the search (line 36). Otherwise there's a race condition if the document has been committed to the index yet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with the same problem using pyes 0.19.1, but I'm able to retrieve a single field from the result set.

Replace this line:

```
resultset = ES.search(query=q, indices='oolong', fields=["name"])
```

to this one:

```
resultset = ES.search(query=q, indices='oolong', fields="name")
```

This works for me. I haven't figured out how to retrieve multiple fields though. When I pass a list to *fields* it always returns empty dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

```
class pyes.query.Search(...)
```

There you can set a fields array.
Fields on ES.search is not working.

```
es_connection = ES(server=[('http', 'localhost', '9200')])
q = Search(fields=['field1', 'field2'], .....)
resultset = es_connection.search(
    q,
    ....
)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use this

```
resultset = ES.search(query=q, indices='oolong', fields="name")
```

or in case you have more than one field use

```
resultset = ES.search(query=q, indices='oolong', fields="name,id")
```